# Rocket couldn't parse JSON body

Tags: json, rust, postman, rust-rocket

I am trying to make a POST request with Postman to my Rust API:

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use rocket_contrib::json::{Json, JsonValue};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Response {
    status: String,
}

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

#[post("/register", format = "json", data = "<register>")]
fn user_create(register: Json<Response>) -> Json<Response> {
    Json(Response {
        status: "works".to_string(),
    })
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", routes![index, user_create])
        .launch();
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "hello-rocket"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [""]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.6"
serde = { version = "1.0", feature = ["derive"]}
serde_json = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "0.4.6"
default-features = false
features = ["json"]
```

I have configured a `Content-Type: application/json` header within Postman and the body of my request is `{"status": "running"}`:

[image]

I am getting

```
Error: Couldn't parse JSON body: Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0)
```

Comment: This code seems to work for me. Double check everything: correct request (POST /register), correct host, latest build, ensure there aren't any weird bytes in your request. If that doesn't work, include your dependencies' versions and a reproducible sample (rocket `.mount`, `.launch` and all).

Comment: @kmdreko I updated my cargo and rustup version, and make sure all my dependencies are in their latest version. I even created a new project to test it out and it still does not work.

Comment: Add your full code and cargo.toml to your post

Comment: This isn't a Rust problem: `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"status": "running"}' http://localhost:8000/register` ==> `{"status":"works"}`. You must be misusing postman.

Comment: You also have warnings. **Always** address **all** warnings when you are trying to debug a problem! `warning: unused manifest key: dependencies.serde.feature`

Comment: runnig the exact same curl command gives me 404.

Comment: Again, this code seems to work for me. If it fails with both postman and curl then something else is going on. The error you see is when the json header is set but there is no body. So either there's code you're not showing or something is stripping out the body of your request (proxy, firewall, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Set the postman headers "Content-Type" and "Content-Length":

[postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awfVO.png)

[
"work..."
]